# Timeout on finding submit button on Vimeo login screen

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to find and click a button on Vimeo's login screen.   The code goes to [www.vimeo.com](http://www.vimeo.com). Click the "Login" button. A login popup with iframe shows up. My code fill in the email and password and click the submit button. Puppeteer times out on the submit button.

I use the inspect tool to get the XPath to the button button.

```
//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section/section[1]/form/section[3]/button
```

```
const VIMEO_ELEMENTS_XPATH = {
  LOGIN_BUTTON:
    "//*[@id='root']/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/header/nav/div[2]/button[1]",
  SUBMIT_BUTTON:
    "//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section/section[1]/form/section[3]/button",
}

...

      const elementHandle = await page.waitForSelector('#iframeReg');
      const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
      try {
        await typeBySelector(frame, "LOGIN_EMAIL_INPUT_FRAME", EMAIL);
        await typeBySelector(frame, "LOGIN_PASSWORD_INPUT_FRAME", PASSWORD);
        await clickByXpath(frame, "SUBMIT_BUTTON"); 
        await page.waitForNavigation();
        log("Successfully logged in to vimeo");
      } catch (err) {
        log("Failed to log in to vimeo");
        throw err;
      }

...

const clickByXpath = async (
  page,
  xpathkey,
  fail_silently = false,
  { delay } = {}
) => {
  const xpath = VIMEO_ELEMENTS_XPATH[xpathkey];
  try {
    if (delay) page.waitForTimeout(delay);
    await page.waitForXPath(xpath, { timeout: 10000 });
    const [element] = await page.$x(xpath);
    await element.click();
  } catch (err) {
    if (fail_silently) return;
    console.log(`===> Failed: didn't find element`, xpathkey);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

But I am getting a timeout error finding the button

```
TimeoutError: waiting for XPath `//*[@id='__next']/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/section/section[1]/form/section[3]/button` failed: timeout 10000ms exceeded
```

[image: inspect]

An suggestion on how to fix the code to find the submit button.

Comment: Try to find the button with its text, avoid using complex paths to get an item

Comment: @JuanDa237 There is no name or id, unfortunately.

<button format="primary" class="sc-furwcr grswkD sc-8u8vw5-1 eVQZqE f2pPilotRegLogin"><span class="sc-iCfMLu ktdbzG">Log in with an email</span><div radius="12" class="sc-hKwDye czsCWl"></div></button>

Comment: Please share code [as text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). What site specifically is the Vimeo login screen you want to automate?

Comment: @ggorlen The relevant code is in my post.  The code goes to https://vimeo.com. Click the "Login" button. A login popup with iframe shows up.  My code fill in the email and password and click the submit button.  Puppeteer times out on the submit button.

Comment: Thanks, but please share a [mcve], with all URLs and navigations. It's much easier to help if I can copy, paste and run instead of guessing the missing code, which is often part of the problem.

Comment: I understand your point. I didn't write the code, but I need to fix the login issue.  Let me see if I can extract the code into a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @John2 I mean if the button says "Login with email" try to get the button with that text, not with complex paths that could change in the future or that doesnt work.